# how to bind a link local address to an ipv6 socket

Tags: c, ipv6

This question can be treated as a sister question of [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455762/why-cant-i-bind-ipv6-socket-to-a-linklocal-address) posted by myself. It is very tedious that when you want to bind a link local address to an IPv6 socket, you need to set the `sin6_scope_id` field of the `sockaddr_in6` struct. I'm wondering if someone can provide a solution following good practice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The IPv6 link-local address is not unique on the node it's only unique for the NIC which is why you have to specify the scope-id.  In other words it is perfectly valid to have multiple adapters with exactly the same IPv6 address.

This means you should take in as input the scope-id or suitable text form (%eth0, %1) that you can pass to `getaddrinfo()`.

One method is to take in a IPv6 link-local address, enumerate the interfaces and if only one matches use that, if more than one match then bail out with a list of interfaces and get the user to specify which one in full form.

Comment: The link-local address is formed from its routing prefix and the MAC address of the interface. So if multiple adapters are available on the same host, each network adapter has a different link-local address.

Comment: @Zind you are incorrectly assuming each interface has a unique MAC address.  See Sun hardware for a counter-example.

Answer (score 4):

For IPv6 link-local addresses (`fe80::/10` prefix), the `sin6_scope_id` member in the `sockaddr_in6` structure is the interface number and you can get this number by

```
if_nametoindex(const char *ifname);
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue only arises when you hardcode a link local address, which is not really a practical solution for a nontrivial app.

Otherwise, you should be getting your `sockaddr` to bind from [`getifaddrs()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html), which will fill out the scope id for you (eg. you can allow your user to specify an interface name, then search through the list returned by `getifaddrs()` to find the link-local address associated with that interface).